# How to create three groups from a case when statement using two groups when records are on different rows

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a dataset with a list of codes and the records are divided into two categories, `LD` and `A`

```
ID  Type
1   LD
2   A
1   A
1   LD
3   LD
```

These two categories are allocated based on the codes they have.
However, there are a few records where the ID is the same and it has some with type 'LD' and some with type 'A'. In such instances, I want the 'Type' column for these records to say 'LD_A' like below. All the record with ID 1 have changed to LD_A (because they belong to both the types) retaining the number of rows-

```
ID  Type
1   LD_A
2   A
1   LD_A
1   LD_A
3   LD
```

Can someone please guide me as to how to do this in sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by ID and get only those IDs, that have multiple different Types. You can do this with this query:

```
SELECT ID FROM t GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Type) > 1
```

Then you join this query to the table in an UPDATE statement to "filter" the records. (It also needs to be this way, because you can't use WHERE and a subquery on the same table in an update query).

Anyway, here's your final query:

```
UPDATE t 
JOIN (SELECT ID FROM t GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Type) > 1) ft USING (ID)
SET Type = 'LD_A';
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66d22a/1/0)

Comment: Thank you. But that doesn't seem to work. It gives me a syntax error on the word JOIN in line 2. I am using and updating a temp table. Will that be a problem?

Comment: Please doublecheck any copy-paste errors. As you can see it works for me. Also note, a syntax error message displays the first position of what MySQL considers as garbage. So the error is usually on the left of it. In your case maybe there's something wrong with the table name?

Comment: UPDATE ##P 
JOIN (SELECT id FROM ##P GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Type]) > 1) ft USING (id)
SET [Type] = 'LD_A'...That's the code syntax I am using

Comment: You can't have `#` in a table name, that's used to comment things.

Comment: I see. Then what's the syntax to create a temp table? I thought ## is for global temp tables and # for local ones?

Comment: `create temporary table foo(id int);` There are no global temp tables. We're talking about MySQL, right?

Comment: No sorry. I am using the Microsoft SQL server 2012.

Comment: Hm, try to put the table name in square brackets, please. Like `[##P]`

Comment: Hm, I'm not familiar enough with SQL Server. The statement however should still work, as this is simple standard SQL. The problem is elsewhere. Is there something special you do before the UPDATE statement?

Comment: IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Patients') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Patients

SELECT
a.combid
,...list of columns here
INTO ##P
FROM 'table name'
INNER JOIN [Another table] ON ....x......LEFT JOIN [TABLE3] ON....Y...


WHERE 'conditions listed'
order by combid

UPDATE [##P]
join(
SELECT combid FROM [##P] GROUP BY combid HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Type]) > 1)  USING(combid)
set [Type]='LD_A'.....That's the code I am using..

Comment: You need to finish your SELECT statement with `;`

Comment: Thank you for all your help. But that doesn't seem to work. Anyway, I will have a closer look now. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mytable
JOIN mytable AS mytable2 ON mytable2.id=mytable.id AND mytable2.`Type`='A'
SET mytable.`Type`='LD_A', mytable2.`Type`='LD_A', 
WHERE mytable.`type`='LD';
```

This finds all records with type 'LD' that also have a record 'A' with the same ID, and then updates both to 'LD_A'

Answer (score 0):

```
     --- SOURCE
                       IF ( EXISTS ( SELECT    *
                                  FROM      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                                  WHERE     TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
                                            AND TABLE_NAME = 'TBL' ) )
                        BEGIN
                            DROP TABLE TBL
                        END


                    CREATE TABLE TBL
                        (
                          id INT ,
                          [type] VARCHAR(10)
                        )

                    INSERT  INTO TBL
                    VALUES  ( 1, 'LD' ),
                            ( 2, 'A' ),
                            ( 1, 'A' ),
                            ( 1, 'LD' ),
                            ( 3, 'LD' )

        PRINT 'Before Update'
        SELECT * FROM TBL

--- QUERY
        ;WITH CTE AS (
                    SELECT  t.id ,
                            IIF(EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                                         FROM   ( SELECT    MAX(ctr) ctr ,
                                                            id
                                                  FROM      ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ) ctr ,
                                                                        id
                                                              FROM      tbl
                                                            ) T
                                                  GROUP BY  id
                                                ) TblXT
                                         WHERE  TblXT.id = t.id
                                                AND ctr > 1 ), typeR, type) [typeNew],
                                                type
                    FROM    ( SELECT    id ,
                                        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(STUFF(( SELECT  QUOTENAME([TYPE])
                                                                        FROM    TBL
                                                                        GROUP BY [TYPE]
                                                                        ORDER BY type DESC
                                                                      FOR
                                                                        XML PATH('')
                                                                      ), 1, 0, ''), '][', '_'),
                                                        '[', ''), ']', '') [typeR] ,
                                        tbl.[type]
                              FROM      TBL
                            ) T

            )
        UPDATE CTE
        SET type = typeNew


        PRINT 'After Update'
        SELECT * FROM TBL
```

Result

```
    Before Update
    id          type
    ----------- ----------
    1           LD
    2           A
    1           A
    1           LD
    3           LD

    (5 row(s) affected)



    After Update
    id          type
    ----------- ----------
    1           LD_A
    2           A
    1           LD_A
    1           LD_A
    3           LD

    (5 row(s) affected)
```